# user authorization with equals() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a blog in which a user can only edit it the blogs they created. But now I want to make an admin that can edit and delete any post he wants.

```
if(foundBlog.author.id.equals(
     req.user._id ||
     foundBlog.author.username === "ADMIN"
)) {
    next();
} else {
    res.redirect("back");
}
```

But my code doesn't work.

Comment: *My code doesn't work.* How so? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

equals() is not a valid String function except you have implemented this yourself. If you haven't and want to, you could do something as simple as

```
String.prototype.equals = function(str){
   return this.toString() === str;
}
```

and then

```
"hello".equals("hello")  // gives true
"hello".equals("kitty") // gives false
```

However, I would advice against poisoning the prototype of a well-known/built-in object or any shared global space for that matter cause that is a recipe for disaster.

With that said, I'll just go for the strict equality comparison.

```
if(foundBlog.author.id === req.user._id || foundBlog.author.username === "ADMIN")
```

No harm no foul.